# ROR 4 - User authentication failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

Hi I am a beginner at ROR 4 learning via tutorials. Now I made this beginner cms app but I am unable to login again into it using the login page I created. I have checked using rails console that username and password that I am typing are real and exist in the database and I have tried creating new user through console, but still I can't get myself to login into the app. This is making me nuts, not being able to login into your own app.

Here's my login page code

```
<% @page_title = "Admin Login" %>

<div class="login">
  <%= form_tag(:action => 'attempt_login') do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:username) %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag(:username) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:password) %></td>
      <td><%= password_field_tag(:password) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= submit_tag("Log In") %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my controller code

```
layout 'admin'

  before_action :confirm_logged_in, :except => [:login, :attempt_login, :logout]

  def index
    # display text & links
  end

  def login
    # login form
  end

  def attempt_login
    if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
      found_user = AdminUser.where(:username => params[:username]).first
      if found_user
        authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      end
    end
    if authorized_user
      # mark user as logged in
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      session[:username] = authorized_user.username
      flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination."
      redirect_to(:action => 'login')
    end
  end

  def logout
    # mark user as logged out
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:username] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Logged out"
    redirect_to(:action => "login")
  end

end
```

Would really appreciate help on this matter.

Comment: If you are getting invalid username/pass.. you should check whether `found_user.authenticate(params[:password])` is actually returning `true` or not.

Comment: I did check using rails console and yes it is returning true. And i have tried this many a times using different users, creating different user and then again checking it. But the same error persists.

Comment: And if there is any way check that statement, please do let me know.

Comment: check it in the controller file itself. write `puts authorized_user` just after you are assigning it and check in development log whether you are getting true there or not.

Comment: I dont think it is getting authorized.

Comment: if you got false then find out why you got that. write more `puts` statements and test more variables. Make sure that everything is getting value what you think they should get.

Comment: @sonalkr132 I tried writing more puts statement to output the username and password to see if it was taking the right values to authenticate with. And as it comes it is taking the right set of values, but why it is not authenticating is still a mystery to me. If I use the same values in rails console, everything works fine. User gets authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - don't put your authentication into your UsersController or ApplicationController. This is important stuff. It merits a controller of its own.

Also in Rails the restful CRUD conventions are pretty important. So how would you treat user logins as a resource?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # display the form to sign a user in
  # GET /session/new
  def new
    @user = AdminUser.new
  end

  # verify that the user is who he says he is and log them in.
  # POST /session
  def create
     reset_session
     @user = AdminUser.find_by(username: admin_user_params[:username])
     if @user && @user.authenticate(admin_user_params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are now logged in."
     else
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid username/password combination."
        @user = AdminUser.new 
        render :new 
     end
  end

  # sign a user out
  # DELETE /session
  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have been signed out."
  end

  private

    def admin_user_params
      params.require(:admin_user).permit(:password, :username)
    end
end
```

Notice that we call `reset_session` before the login and log out. This invalidates the session key - this prevents a form of vulnerability known as session fixation where an attacker steals your users cookies.

Also note that we don't differentiate between when the user enters a wrong username or password. This is one way to guard against a rainbow attack where a hacker first guesses usernames and then uses a rainbow table containing common passwords to break in with brute force. This makes guessing the usernames a bit harder.

But we also need some routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Note here that we use the singular resource. That's because from user point of view there is only one session - their own.

And we also need a form (`views/session/new.html.erb`):

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: { action: :create, controller: :sessions }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Instead of troubleshooting your code I think it might be helpful to look at the "rails" way of doing it.

Comment: So you just created new sessions instead of just directly authenticating the already present users and then assigning them sessions.

Comment: Sorry if I come out to be naive but I am really really new to this. It's been only a week since i started learning ROR. And I think i haven't put the authentication in application controller but I created an access controller. The code from which is pasted above.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean by "already present users". You simply check if the form submission matches the record you have in your database. If the username/pw combination matches you save the users id in the session. Otherwise you render the form again.

Comment: The AdminUser model in the new action only exists in the servers memory - it is just used to bind the form inputs to a model. It is gone as soon as the form is actually sent to user.

Comment: Thank you man. Your codes worked with a few modifications of mine but I am still unclear as to why my earlier codes wouldn't work. They both look the same doing the same thing.